# Does it hurt a laptop if I take off its screen?

Tags: laptop

Does taking the top part of a laptop off (on a laptop with a fluorescent screen and wi-fi antennas and no webcam) ruin the laptop if it is used this way? If not, are there any other risks to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the wifi antenna goes up into the screen. But otherwise, no.